# Spring Boot JCache metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use JCache with EhCache 3 in Spring Boot 2 and want to monitor metrics like hit rate or cache size ([https://docs.spring.io/](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-datasource-cache)). To achieve that, I enabled actuators and looked at `localhost:8080/actuators/caches`, which listed all my created caches, but not the actual metrics I need. The only field listed for each cache is `target`. The response looks like this:

```
{
  "cacheManagers": {
    "ehCacheManager": {
      "caches": {
        "cache1": {
          "target": "org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache"
        },
        "cache2": {
          "target": "org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache"
        }
      },
    },
  }
}
```

I create the caches like this:

```
  @Bean
  public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
    var cacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider("org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider")
        .getCacheManager();

    cacheManager.destroyCache("cache1");

    var cacheConfig = CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
        String.class,
        Integer.class,
        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(1000)
    ).build();
    cacheManager.createCache("cache1",Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig));
    cacheManager.enableStatistics("cache1", true);

    return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
  }
```

How do I include all metrics (that should be provided by JCache) to the caches endpoint of the actuator?

Comment: Did you try quering the metrics endpoint provided by actuator? Any helpful information there?

Comment: It shows some aggregated values (cache.gets, cache.puts, ...) but nothing specific for any cache.  Specifically, I want to get these: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-datasource-cache

Comment: Did you made use of the caches before trying to get their metrics? Some times metrics only created the first time they have value.

Comment: I just tried it but with no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were actually several problems going on which I want to describe here for others if they stumble upon similar issues:

1. `spring.main.lazy-initialization` was set to `true` in my configuration, this lead to the bean `CacheMetricsRegistrar` not being loaded at application start. Setting this value to `false` temporarily lead to the metrics appearing in /actuator/metrics.

The solution to resolve this permanently was to create a second class which actually creates the caches. This class got the annotation `@Lazy(false)` as well as a dependency to `CacheMetricsRegistrar`.

2. Now the metrics were available, but they did not include the caches configured (cache1). Appearently I have to add them manually to the registrar to make the metrics appear in the actuator like this:

```
jCacheManager.createCache(name,Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig));
jCacheManager.enableStatistics(name, true);
    
registrar.bindCacheToRegistry(cacheManager.getCache(name));
```

I had to use the bean `JCacheCacheManager` to create the cache and `CacheManager` to access it in a way for the registrar to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Acutuator's `/actuator/caches` endpoint only shows the configured caches. For cache metrics you should use the following ones:

`/actuator/metrics/cache.gets`
`/actuator/metrics/cache.puts`
`/actuator/metrics/cache.evictions`
`/actuator/metrics/cache.removals`

Hitting those will show the corresponding metrics for all available caches. If you need to target a specific cache, say `cache1`, you can do it like so:

`/actuator/metrics/cache.gets?tag=name:cache1`

Make sure to expose the `metrics` endpoint by adding it to the `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` app property, i.e.:

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=caches,metrics`

You might need these properties as well:

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.caches.enabled=true
```

Here's an example output of `/actuator/metrics/cache.gets`:

```json
{
  "name": "cache.gets",
  "description": "The number of times cache lookup methods have returned a cached (hit) or uncached (newly loaded or null) value (miss).",
  "baseUnit": null,
  "measurements": [
    {
      "statistic": "COUNT",
      "value": 0.0
    }
  ],
  "availableTags": [
    {
      "tag": "result",
      "values": [
        "hit",
        "miss"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "cache.manager",
      "values": [
        "eh"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "cache",
      "values": [
        "cache1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: My problem is, under `/actuator/metrics` i don't see any of the metrics you listed. Do I have to enable them somehow separately? I added the configs you suggested as well with no effect.

Comment: `/actuator/metrics` endpoint only lists the names of the metrics available. It doesn't show any details. To get the values you need to request a specific metric by its name like `/actuator/metrics/cache.gets`. To enable these no other config params are needed except for the ones I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks to your help i found enough information to solve the issue (as documented in my answer). Thank you very much!